# Почему не работает сравнение прямых и обратных итераторов

Tags: c++

Не могу понять почему не работает сравнение прямого и обратного итератора. В интернете не смог найти информации. Простите за вопрос. Я только начал изучать STL.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vectArray;

    vectArray.push_back(19);
    vectArray.push_back(18);
    vectArray.push_back(17);
    vectArray.push_back(11);
    vectArray.push_back(12);
    vectArray.push_back(13);

    vector<int>::iterator itarFront;
    vector<int>::reverse_iterator itarBack;

    itarFront = vectArray.begin();
    itarBack = vectArray.rbegin();

    while (itarFront != itarBack)
    {
        swap(*itarFront, *itarBack);
        itarFront++;
        if(itarFront == itarBack)
            break;
        itarBack++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор выдает:

> C:\Users\evilnw\Documents\test1\main.cpp:27: ошибка: no match for
>   'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::vector::iterator {aka
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}' and 'std::vector::reverse_iterator {aka
>   std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >}')
>        while (itarFront != itarBack)

Comment: Раз уж учите стандартную библиотеку, вот Вам в одну строку Ваши мытарства с итераторами: `std::reverse(vectArray.begin(), vectArray.end());`

Comment: Если делать как Вы задумали, то основной цикл получится вот таким "однострочником": `while (itarFront != itarBack.base())
 swap(*itarFront++, *itarBack++);`

Comment: Только сравнение все же д.б. на `<`, а не на `!=`. Т.е. `while (itarFront < itarBack.base()) swap(*itarFront++, *itarBack++);`

Answer (score 1):

А почему собственно оно должно работать? Только одинаковые итераторы можно сравнивать. Используй парами `begin` и `end` или `rbegin` и `rend`. Итераторы можно не только инкрементить, но и декрементить.

И как бонус, ещё 2 бага:

1. Упадёт при пустом векторе на разыменовании.
2. <s>Условие всегда ложно, если количество элементов чётное.</s>
   Сорри, не заметил if. Но это костыль. Лучше просто `<` использовать.

PS: Возможно, можно сравнить так: `&*itarFront != &*itarBack`, но я *не рекомендую* так делать.

Comment: Спасибо. С прямыми работало прекрасно. Решил попробовать с прямым и обратным, но не получилось. Вот и появился вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Реверсивные итераторы имеют метод `base`, который позволяет получить основной итератор.

Ваша программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vectArray;

    vectArray.push_back( 19 );
    vectArray.push_back( 18 );
    vectArray.push_back( 17 );
    vectArray.push_back( 11 );
    vectArray.push_back( 12 );
    vectArray.push_back( 13 );

    for ( std::vector<int>::iterator it = vectArray.begin();
          it != vectArray.end();
          ++it )
    {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::vector<int>::iterator itarFront;
    std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator itarBack;

    itarFront = vectArray.begin();
    itarBack  = vectArray.rbegin();

    while ( itarFront != itarBack.base() )
    {
        std::swap( *itarFront, *itarBack );
        ++itarFront;
        if  ( itarFront != itarBack.base() ) ++itarBack;
    }

    for ( std::vector<int>::iterator it = vectArray.begin();
          it != vectArray.end();
          ++it )
    {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль следующий:

```
19 18 17 11 12 13 
13 12 11 17 18 19
```

Итераторы класса `std::vector` являются итераторами произвольного доступа, а значит и двунаправленными. Поэтому не было необходимости использовать реверсивный итератор.
Если ваш компилятор поддерживает `C++ 2011`, то код программы может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vectArray = { 19, 18, 17, 11, 12, 13 };

    for ( int x : vectArray ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( auto first = vectArray.begin(), last = vectArray.end();
          first != last && first != --last;
          ++first )
    {
        std::iter_swap( first, last );
    }          

    for ( int x : vectArray ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

То же самое можно сделать, используя стандартный алгоритм `std::reverse`, объявленный в заголовке `<algorithm>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vectArray = { 19, 18, 17, 11, 12, 13 };

    for ( int x : vectArray ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::reverse( vectArray.begin(), vectArray.end() );

    for ( int x : vectArray ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

В обоих случаях вывод программы будет таким же, как и в первом случае

```
19 18 17 11 12 13 
13 12 11 17 18 19
```

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем использовать обратный и прямой итераторы одновременно, сделайте из обратного итератора прямой вот так:

```
itarBack.base()
```

Исправьте это в тех трёх местах, где вы одновременно их используете: при сравнении и при обмене.

Прочитать подробнее про действия над обратным итератором можно здесь: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/reverse_iterator/

---

Вот у меня такой получился цикл:

```
while (itarFront != itarBack.base())
{
    // вначале сдвигаем обратный итератор, а затем используем
    itarBack++;
    iter_swap(itarFront, itarBack.base());
    itarFront++;
}
```

Comment: При обмене-то зачем? Там разыменовываются они и меняются значения.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну, да, точно. А не лучше ли заменить swap на iter_swap?

Comment: А в чём выигрыш от него?

Comment: @mymedia, лучше. Раз функция есть, нужно её использовать. Ну и приведите исправленный код в ответе, а не просто рекомендацию, что и где исправить.

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо за разъяснения :)

Comment: уберите последний `if`, он бесполезен. и `base` не нужен в `iter_swap`

Comment: @ixSci, я заметил, уже исправил :)

Comment: @ixSci, `base()` не нужно убирать, иначе будет по-другому работать

Comment: Не прав я, мой цикл упадёт на других данных. Хотя и Ваш тоже. Всё-таки нужна проверка, как у автора.

Comment: Продублирую-ка комментарий в вопросе (а то ведь нет теперь нотификации участников темы) и здесь: `while (itarFront != itarBack.base()) swap(*itarFront++, *itarBack++);` / Вот и весь цикл реверса, с пустым вектором тоже работает.

Comment: @avp, с чётной длиной не работает. Итераторы никогда не будут равны.

Comment: Ну, да. Только наоборот, с нечетной itarBack.base() будет "проскакивать". / Первое очевидное решение `while (itarFront < itarBack.base()) swap(*itarFront++, *itarBack++);` это заменить `!=` на `<`. Второе, отказаться в таких циклах от итераторов (все же они нужны для "обобщенного" программирования и использования <algorithm>) и очевидно и просто писать с индексами или указателями.

Answer (score -1):

Для информации:

```
std::reverse(vectArray.begin(), vectArray.end());
```